# Как скачать много url из файла txt через powershell get-content?

Tags: windows, powershell

Пытаюсь воспользоваться

```
get-content C:\fileWithLinks.txt | foreach {Start-BitsTransfer -Source
$_ -Destination 'G:\folderForDownload' -transfertype download}
```

Но вылазит ошибка:

> Start-BitsTransfer : Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки
> или метке тома. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x8007007B) строка:1 знак:39
> ...  | foreach {Start-BitsTransfer -Source $_ -Destination
> 'G:\folderForDownload' -tr ...
> CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Start-BitsTransfer], FileNotFoundException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.NewBitsTransferCommand

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: ¿Тут случаем `foreach ` не перепутан с `ForEach-Object`?